# How do I use MaxMind's GeoIP database to determine location?

Tags: java, geolocation, location, inet

So, I was told in my previous question that I can use the [databases provided by MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite) to determine locations.

So, I got their databases downloaded from their site. They are `csv` files and open up in Excel.

`InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost()` is how I get the IP of my computer. From there I do `String justIP = ip.getHostAddress()`

My question is:

How do I resolve `justIP` to a city location using the DB I just downloaded ???

I am new to this so a little help will be appreciated.

One of the files has three columns. `startIPNum`, `endIPNum` and `locID` I do not know what these do but I guess `locID` maps to a city and country location in the other file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried the Java examples from Maxmind? http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable#Java-8
And see http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/csv for field descriptions

Comment: That worked for me. Just a question: if I convert their `source` folder into a JAR, will I be able to use it as a dependency in Eclipse project ?

Comment: 1. Compile: `cd source/com/maxmind/geoip/`   
`javac *.java` 2. pack: you can use any zip util,  3. add to buildpath (don't forget to put it also in classpath on target system)