# Find IP address city,country Java

Tags: java, location, ip, geoip

I wan't to find City,State,Country of an IP address. I have looked up for a while and I got GeoIp2 (But they need userId and License key). Is there any other way to do this. I'm using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously? https://www.google.com/#q=java+geoip+free&safe=active

Here are the top results:

- [How do I use MaxMind's GeoIP database to determine location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746169/how-do-i-use-maxminds-geoip-database-to-determine-location)
- https://github.com/ebourg/geoip-java
- [Java library to get geo-code from ipaddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298462/java-library-to-get-geo-code-from-ipaddress)